# Resize NSPopover after it is shown

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nspopover

I have an NSPopover who's content in an NSView. I create the popover and add the view like this:

```
NSPopover *thePopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
[thePopover setContentViewController:myViewController];
```

I then show the popover and set the size:

```
[thePopover setContentSize:NSMakeSize(300.0f, 160.0f)];
```

At this point the popover is visible and its content view is correct. Is there a way that I can resize the popover at this point without closing and re-showing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by calling back to the controller that launched the popover via a delegate protocol and resetting the size using the `setContentSize:`

Comment: how did you do that?

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPopover/contentSize):

> The popover's content size is set to match the size of the content view when the content view controller is set.

So, [set the frame](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setFrame%3a) of the popover's content view.

Comment: This seems like the simplest answer.

Answer (score 3):

`NSWindow` has private property `_popover` that store a reference to `NSPopover`.
You can use it to access to `NSPopover` instance from any `NSViewController` (and then call `setContentSize:` on it) like this:

```
- (NSPopover *)popover
{
    NSWindow *window = self.view.window;
    NSPopover *popover = [window valueForKey:@"_popover"];
    return popover;
}
```